# Dependency graph for Rails partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my current Ruby on Rails view we have many views and partials. So many in fact that it's not clear which view uses which partial (which itself may use other partials as well).

The question is if there's a tool out there that generates a dependency graph of all views and partials (ideally generating a graph, but that's easy to do) or how you have solved this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a plugin (basically just a rake task) that generates a graph containing all the dependencies of the views and partials for you.

Get it at http://github.com/msales/partial_dependencies/tree/master

Comment: The code is for Rails 2. The only change required for Rails 3 appears to be to change RAILS_ROOT in line 5 to Rails.root.

Answer (score 2):

Should be relatively simple to do reading all views and partials and creating a directed graph on the fly, the only thing you need to be carefull about is loops.

Answer (score 1):

[Noisy Partials](http://github.com/gwynm/noisy_partials) could be what you need (although I've not actually tried it).